# Does the Sequelize sync method wait for a connection before executing?

Tags: sequelize.js

After testing out this code, I was confused that my tables got created. I would have expected not to have been connected when the .sync method was called. Is the sync() method somehow waiting until the connection is established?

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var chalk = require('chalk');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost/nfldb');

sequelize.define('team', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(function(){
    console.log(chalk.green('connected to database ' + sequelize.config.database));
  })
  .catch(function(er){
    console.log(chalk.red(er.message));
  });


sync();

function sync(){
  sequelize.sync({force: true})
    .then(function(){
      console.log(chalk.green('database has been synced'));
    })
    .catch(function(){
      console.log(chalk.red('unable to sync database'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sync` automatically requests a connection to the DB. `authenticate` is meant to be used to check whether you can connect to the database without executing a real query - as far as I recall it does `SELECT 1 + 1`. It is not required to call `authenticate`, it's only menat as a convenience method.